# Yii ajax checkBox with two urls

Tags: ajax, url, checkbox, yii

I have a checkBox in Yii and I use ajax in it. What I want to do is the use one 'url' parameter when the checkBox is checked and another different when it is unchecked.

For example, when checked:

```
'url'=> CController::createUrl('/item/add'),
```

When unchecked

```
'url'=> CController::createUrl('/item/remove'),
```

What is the best approach for it? Of course I do not want to check the state of the view checkBox from the controller.

Thank you

Comment: Why not write a jQuery listener and change the URL according to whether or not the checkbox is checked?

Comment: But I just want to change the 'url' parameter of the ajax call. Is it possible? I have thought to change the checkBox for a button group, so each button has its own ajax call, with its own 'url' parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk">
<?php 
        $url1 = $this->createUrl('/item/add');
        $url2 = $this->createUrl('/item/remove');
        $js = '
        $(\'#chk\').change(function(){
            $.post(this.checked ? "'.$url1.'" : "'.$url2.'", function(data) {
                $("#items").html(data);
            });
        });
        ';
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('chk', $js);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I would do jQuery, like:

```
 var url = '';
 if($('#chbInput').val() == 1)
 { 
      //do something when checked
      url = '<?php echo CController::createUrl('/item/add') ?>';
      ...
 }
 else
 {
      url = '<?php CController::createUrl('/item/remove') ?>';
      ...
 }
```

Comment: But in Yii the ajax declaration is a php array, I do not know how could I manage it in jQuery. What I have is something like 'ajax'=>array('url'=> CController::createUrl('/item/remove'), 'type' => 'POST', success => 'js:function()....'}.

Comment: before you declare that array, put an if statement to check for that condition.